# Why is there a little computer on my Chrome Widget?

Tags: macos, display

I cannot see to figure out why it pops up.
I have my widget with my own webpages open but now and again a second chrome widget with the computer screen comes up. Sometimes it's even there all day. Not sure if someone is spying or mirroring my screen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a “Handoff” indicator, I think. If you have Chrome open on another device (e.g. an iPad) you can click the icon to continue what you’re doing on your Mac. For example:

[image]